# How to support line number when using pygments with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, pygments

How can I number the code lines which are highlighted using pygments in Jekyll?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to the [Liquid Extensions](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Liquid-Extensions) wiki page of the Jekyll documentation, the `highlight` Liquid tag has an optional second parameter, which may have the value `linenos` to turn on line numbering:

```
{% highlight language linenos %}
your code here
{% endhighlight %}
```

Use it with caution. With `linenos` the line numbers are actually inserted in the code's text, so will be impossible to copy the code block without them. (This could be solved by letting the visitor to `$('.lineno').toggle()` the line numbers' visibility. Works in Firefox, not sure if is portable.)

**Update**: Better use `linenos=table`:

```
{% highlight language linenos=table %}
your code here
{% endhighlight %}
```

That will place the code in a `table` with two cells: first `td` all the line numbers, second `td` the code itself. This makes possible to select only the code, without the line numbers.

Comment: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb#L23 This makes me think there is a way to make them not inline if I can find the right keyword

Comment: Great question. It made me do some research on Pygments side. Updated the answer.

Comment: Now just have to fix css and I am all set. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've tried that way but I get errors in Maruku due table not closed, you know anything about that @manatwork?

Comment: Sorry @alex88, not met such error. But I experienced strange errors with Maruku, so I use [kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/) instead as it seems to be much more stable.

Comment: @manatwork thanks for the reply, btw yeah I've got it solved too changing markdown parser ;) Thanks again!

Comment: You can prevent the user from selecting line numbers using CSS, rather than the table format, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/85662.